# Axis with Border

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

[image]

I am new to tikz and have been trying to create different graphics.  I am trying to get a nice grid around the axis (like shown above). I am having trouble. I have tried several things, but nothing seems to work.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[step=1cm,opacity=0.25] (0,0) grid (5.5,5.5);
\begin{axis}[
axis x line=center,
axis y line=center,
xmin=-10,xmax=10
ymin=-10.5,ymax=10
xtick={-5,-4,...,5},
ytick={-5,-4,...,5},
]
  
\end{axis}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: fixed the formatting from original based off a suggestion.  Still could use help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `grid = both` like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
\footnotesize
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis x line = center,
    axis y line = center,
    xmin = -5,   xmax = 5,
    ymin = -5,   ymax = 5,
    xtick = {-5,-4,...,5},
    ytick = {-5,-4,...,5},
    grid  = both,
]
\addplot[mark=none,samples=250,thick]{x^3};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Surely very good. I will put also the arrows in the function.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone!